# Entity Framework 6 Ambient Transaction from WCF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Does EF6 no longer join ambient transactions?

I have transactions flowing from higher level WCF services and I need my EF context to join, and honor, that transaction. I have verified that the transaction is flowing properly.

What I am finding is that if I rollback the higher-level transaction, the data still persists to SQL. I have tried wrapping a transactionscope closer to the call to context.SaveChanges() but that doesn't help. Locally, if I don't commit that transaction then the data doesn't persist.

Inside of my services, this used to be all I had to do:

```
using (var context = new DummyContext())
{
      context.Set<DummyEFEntity>().Add(dummyEFEntity);
      context.SaveChanges();
}
```

What changed and how do I make this work?

Edit* Days later and the best I can guess is that EF 6 is broken when it comes to joining the ambient transaction. In the debugger I can see the transaction propagating down the levels of WCF services, the Transaction identifiers look correct. But, EF is ignoring it - no idea why.

Thanks,
Will

Comment: Can you share the WCF *server* code? Are you propagating the transaction properly? Can you debug and see what the value of Transaction.Current is, before you use the DbContext?

Comment: Sure, in EF6 things have changed considerably in this area, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843#existing). You may have success by using `Database.UseTransaction()`.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Turned out that some new IFX code helping with the transactions was the culprit. There was a transaction in place, but it wasn't the one being flowed (it wasn't flowing). So, after the service exited, that local transaction was committing and the higher one wasn't, but the two were not connected.